# iphone API's for tea time application

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

i want to know what API's in iPhone that we used to:

- Achieve an action by pressing a button
- Show normal input fields
- Give access to a persistent storage
- Realize a count-down timer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Achieve an action by pressing a button

  - `UIButton`'s `-addTarget: action: forControlEvents:` will help you out there.
- Show normal input fields

  - You'll be looking for `UITextField` here.
- Give access to a persistent storage

  - Either use the SQLite C API or Core Data
- Realize a count-down timer

  - Use `NSTimer`.

Comment: Just adding that depending on the amount of data needing for persistent storage, you can use `NSUserDefaults` as well for simple stuff like favorites

Comment: If the answer is helpful you might consider voting it up or even marking it as accepted by click the tick to the left of the answer.